# Can I use the same Apple ID on multiple iPhones/iPods

Tags: app-store, apple-id

We are a commercial entity with an app.  This app will be used by our customers and will be available via AppStore for free.  It needs login and connects to our servers for authentications.  What we want to do is buy the devices, install the app using our single apple ID then "somehow" remove our apple ID so that users can use their own apple ID.

Is this possible?  What are our options?